# Is $\operatorname{int}(A\cup B)=\operatorname{int}(A)\cup\operatorname{int}(B)$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I have posted a counterexample given in a solution below, but when I attempted the problem I did something different.$\DeclareMathOperator{Int}{int}$

**My Attempt**

Take complements of both sides

$$
\Int(A\cup B)\stackrel{?}{=}\Int(A)\cup \Int(B) \\
\big(\Int(A\cup B)\big)^c\stackrel{?}{=}\big(\Int(A)\cup \Int(B)\big)^c \\
\overline{ (A\cup B)^c}\stackrel{?}{=}\overline{(A)^c}\cap \overline{(B)^c}
$$
I got this step from this answer [Prove that the closure of complement, is the complement of the interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970825/prove-that-the-closure-of-complement-is-the-complement-of-the-interior)
$$\overline{ (A)^c\cap (B)^c}\stackrel{?}{=}\overline{(A)^c}\cap \overline{(B)^c}$$

**My question**

Could I prove from where I stopped that the two sides are not equal?  I tried to sketch a ven diagram but both sides seem to give the same intersected set.

---

**Counterexample**

[image]

Comment: From your example, you can get a counterexample to $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline A\cap\overline B$ too.

Comment: Let $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$ thus $\overline{A\cap B}=\emptyset$ and $\overline A\cap\overline B=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proposition.  If the boundaries of A and B are disjoint, then
int A$\cup$B = int A $\cup$ int B.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer to, "does $\operatorname{int}(A\cup B)$ equal $\operatorname{int}(A)\cup\operatorname{int}(B)$?" is:

> Perhaps yes, perhaps no. That depends on which sets $A$ and $B$ are.

So you have no hope of starting out from nothing and then prove that $\operatorname{int}(A\cup B) \ne \operatorname{int}(A)\cup\operatorname{int}(B)$. That conclusion would be as wrong as it is to claim $\operatorname{int}(A\cup B) = \operatorname{int}(A)\cup\operatorname{int}(B)$.

For a claim (with parameters) that is sometimes true and sometimes false, the best you can do is to prove that it is *not always true* (and subsequently that it is not always false). You can't hope to do that by doing *general* manipulations starting from nothing, because that way -- if you do them correctly -- the only thing you will ever reach are things that *always* have such-and-such truth value.

Proving something *not always true* generally takes a concrete counterexample.