# Proving that ${\left( {A \cup B} \right)^{\text{o}}} = \emptyset$ given that ${\left( {\bar A} \right)^{\text{o}}} = \emptyset = {B^{\text{o}}}$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A,B \subseteq X$ such that ${\left( {\bar A} \right)^{\text{o}}} = \emptyset  = {B^{\text{o}}}$. Show that ${\left( {A \cup B} \right)^{\text{o}}} = \emptyset$.

Am I allowed to say that the empty set is a subset of every set so $\emptyset  \subseteq {\left( {A \cup B} \right)^{\text{o}}}$?

I'm struggling with the reverse inclusion: I have the following $ {\left( {A \cup B} \right)^{\text{o}}} \subseteq A \cup B \subseteq \overline {A \cup B}  = \bar A \cup \bar B\ $, but I'm not sure where to go from there?

Comment: Maybe statement is wrong. For example, X is the real numbers, A is the set of rational numbers and B is the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: What does the superscript “0” signify?

Comment: @N.Quy: in that case, $\overline A$ has nonempty interior.

Comment: @AlexM. superscript "o" means interior here.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I see now.

Comment: @MartinArgerami could there be an error in the question, or is the proof N.Quy gave sufficient?

Comment: My proof is way simpler..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ {\left( {\overline A} \right)^{\text{o}}}=\emptyset  \iff {\left ( {\left( {\overline A} \right)^{\text{o}}}  \right)}^c=X$ $ \iff   {\overline {{(A^c)^{\text{o}}}}}=X$.

Then ${(A^c)^{\text{o}}}$ is dense in $X$ or equivalently ${(A^c)^{\text{o}}} \cap \theta \neq \emptyset$ for all non-empty open sets $\theta$ from $X$.

$(A \cup B)^{\text{o}} \cap {(A^c)^{\text{o}}}={\left[ (A \cup B) \cap (A^c) \right]}^{\text{o}}={\left[ B \cap (A^c) \right]}^{\text{o}} \subset B^{\text{o}}=\emptyset$.

Since $(A \cup B)^{\text{o}}$ is open set, it must be empty.

Hence  $(A \cup B)^{\text{o}}= \emptyset$.

Comment: How you get the line 3, since I know that [Interior of Intersection may not equal Intersection of Interiors](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Interior_of_Intersection_may_not_equal_Intersection_of_Interiors).

Comment: There is equality in the case of finite intersection see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Interior_of_Finite_Intersection_equals_Intersection_of_Interiors

Comment: How does one go from ${\left ( {\left( {\overline A} \right)^{\text{o}}}  \right)}^c=X$ to $   {\overline {{(A^c)^{\text{o}}}}}=X$?

Comment: Since $ {\left( E^\text{o} \right)}^c= \overline {E^c}  $ and ${\left( {\overline E} \right)^c}= {\left( E^c \right)}^\text{o}$ for all $E \subset X$ , then ${\left ( {\left( {\overline A} \right)^{\text{o}}}  \right)}^c=\overline {{\left ( {\left( {\overline A} \right)^c}  \right)}}=\overline {  {{\left( A^c \right)}^\text{o}}   }$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U\subseteq A\cup B$ be open.

Then $V=U\setminus \bar A$ is open and $V\subseteq (A\cup B)\setminus \bar A\subseteq B$, so $V=\emptyset$. Thus, $U\subseteq \bar A$, whence $U=\emptyset$.

Note that both conditions are necessary: if $A$ is any set such that $\bar A$ has nonempty interior, then $B=\bar A\setminus A$ will have empty interior and $A\cup B=\bar A$ will not.

Comment: how does V = $null set$ follow from V being a subset of B?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes. The interior of $B$ is empty.

Comment: But B is not necessarily empty

Comment: @AlexM.: Yes. But $V$ is open.

Comment: Yeah I see.  Since V an open set contained it GS to be empty or else B interior wouldn’t be.

Comment: @AlexM.: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $U$ is open, non-empty and $U \subseteq A \cup B$.

Clearly, $U \subseteq \overline{A} \cup B$ as well, and as $\overline{A}$ is closed, $U \setminus \overline{A} = U \cap \overline{A}^\complement$ is open too and must be non-empty (as otherwise $U \subseteq \overline{A}$ which doesn't hold as the interior of $\overline{A}$ is empty!), and by the inclusion we have $U\setminus \overline{A} \subseteq (\overline{A} \cup B)\setminus \overline{A} \subseteq B$, which contradicts $B^\circ=\emptyset$. So no such non-empty $U$ can exist and so $(A \cup B)^\circ = \emptyset$.

Comment: Is there a way to use the given ${\left( {\bar A} \right)^{\text{o}}} = \emptyset$?

Comment: @pabhp I did use it. See edit.

Answer (score -2):

We prove for general case $A=\bar{A}$ since $(A \cap B)^o \subseteq (\bar{A} \cap B )^o$. I use the idea that $A^o= \emptyset$ iff $X=(A^o)^c=\overline{A^c}$

So, we need to prove that $\overline{(A\cup B)^c}=\overline{A^c \cap B^c}=X$ for $A,B \subseteq X$ such that $A$ closed and $A^o=B^o=\emptyset$.

Take any $x \in X$ and any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$. We need to prove that $U \cap A^c \cap B^c \neq \emptyset$.

Since $A^o= \emptyset$ so $\overline{A^c}=X$. Therefore, $U \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$. Take $y \in U \cap A^c$. Since $A$ is closed, $A^c$ is open, there exist an open neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $y \in V \subseteq U \cap A^c$.

Since $B^o = \emptyset$ so $\overline{B^c}=X$. Therefore, for open neighborhood $V$ of $y \in X$, $V\cap B^c \neq \emptyset$. So $U \cap A^c \cap B^c \supset V\cap B^c \neq \emptyset$.

Another way if you're not familiar with the above idea.

By contradiction, assume that there exists $x \in (A \cup B)^o$.

So there must be an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $ x \in U \subset A \cup B$.

- $1^{st}$ case, $ x \in U \subset A$, contradiction to $A^o =\emptyset$.
- $2 ^{nd}$ case, $ x \in U \not\subset A$ there exists $ y \in U$ and $y \notin A$ so $y \in B$. Since $A$ closed, $A^c$ open, so there exists open neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $ y \in V \subset A^c$. So $y \in V \cap U \subset U \subset A \cap B$. Note that $ V \cap U$ is open and $V\cap U \subset V \in A^c$, so $y \in V\cap U \in B$, which contracdicts to $B^o =\emptyset$.

Comment: I dont understand what you are proving. Does this show that ${\left( {A \cup B} \right)^{\text{o}}} = \emptyset$?

Comment: My idea is that $A^o=\emptyset$ iff $(A^o)^c=\overline{A^c}=X$

Comment: FYI, you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970825/prove-that-the-closure-of-complement-is-the-complement-of-the-interior).