# Need some help proving $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash Z$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Need some help with:

> Proof that for $Z \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $\lambda ^n (Z) =0$, then $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash Z$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$

This is what I know so far:

So, to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash Z$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, ie. $\forall \epsilon>0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $(\mathbb{R}^n \backslash Z) \cap B(x,\epsilon) \neq \emptyset $

Comment: What is $\lambda^n$?

Comment: $\lambda ^n$ is supposed to be the lebesgue measure

Comment: Z has no interior, so you can use this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970825/prove-that-the-closure-of-complement-is-the-complement-of-the-interior

Comment: I think it's not possible, because taking $Z=\mathbb{R}$ then there wouldn't exist such $\epsilon$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus Z}=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\mathring{Z}$, it suffices to prove that $\mathring{Z}=\emptyset$. Suppose $\mathring{Z}\neq\emptyset$ and let $x\in\mathring{Z}$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subset Z$ therefore $\lambda(Z)\geqslant\lambda(B(x,\delta))=\delta^n\lambda(B(0,1))>0$ which is a contradiction, thus $\mathring{Z}=\emptyset.$